# How to use ACL in view file in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using ACL functionality in zend framwork.It is working fine.Now i want to check which resources added in ACL from view files.
For Example i added two controller in ACL resources like CmsController and UserController.
Now i want this controller in Layout header.phtml File.
How can i check this ACL in view file ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to save your ACL context in registry, and then in the view access to your registry to retrieve the context ?

Comment: Yes i saved it in registry Zend_Registry::set('acl',$this->acl); but i don't know how to retrive it.

Comment: Try `Zend_Registry::get('acl')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general way, ACLs could be accessed from anywhere. A simple way to do it is :

1) Store it in your registry : `Zend_Registry::set('acl', $myACLObject);`

2) Get it when you want : `Zend_Registry::get('acl');`

For your specific problem, layout has access to each view variables you declared in the controller :

1) Declare your variable in the controller : `$this->view->myVarACL = $myACLObject;`

2) And in the layout, you can do this : `var_dump($this->myVarACL);`